# Applying a Risk Assessment Against Database Entries (Suppliers)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to risk assess suppliers based on several criteria within my suppliers table.

For each supplier, there is a total value of products supplied, and within that, a total value for how many of them are quality assured, and based on the two previous, a percentage value.

Therefore one example would be;

```
FName / Sname / Total / TotalQA / QA%

John  / Smith  /   60   /   30  /  50
```

---

I want to apply a criteria to these records, so if for example the percentage is;

---

<40% - Status = RED

41% - 59% - Status = YELLOW

->60% - Status = GREEN

---

I've thought about making a new table or maybe hard coding new variables, what method would be best for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` statement to do this, something like:

```
SELECT FName, Sname, 
       CASE WHEN QA < 40             THEN 'RED'
            WHEN QA > 40 AND QA < 59 THEN 'YELLOW'
            WHEN QA > 60             THEN 'GREEN'
       END AS 'Status'
FROM Suppliers
```